# What are the meanings of the codes in the NSURLErrorDomain?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nserror

*I'm posting this mostly for reference as I can never find the list when I need it!*

Is there a canonical list of the meanings of the codes for the `NSURLErrorDomain`?

Comment: Good list here: http://nshipster.com/nserror/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes), the list of error codes is as follows:

```
NSURLErrorUnknown = -1,
NSURLErrorCancelled = -999,
NSURLErrorBadURL = -1000,
NSURLErrorTimedOut = -1001,
NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL = -1002,
NSURLErrorCannotFindHost = -1003,
NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004,
NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum = -1103,
NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost = -1005,
NSURLErrorDNSLookupFailed = -1006,
NSURLErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects = -1007,
NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable = -1008,
NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009,
NSURLErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation = -1010,
NSURLErrorBadServerResponse = -1011,
NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication = -1012,
NSURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired = -1013,
NSURLErrorZeroByteResource = -1014,
NSURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData = -1015,
NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData = -1016,
NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse = -1017,
NSURLErrorInternationalRoamingOff = -1018,
NSURLErrorCallIsActive = -1019,
NSURLErrorDataNotAllowed = -1020,
NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted = -1021,
NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist = -1100,
NSURLErrorFileIsDirectory = -1101,
NSURLErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile = -1102,
NSURLErrorSecureConnectionFailed = -1200,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasBadDate = -1201,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted = -1202,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasUnknownRoot = -1203,
NSURLErrorServerCertificateNotYetValid = -1204,
NSURLErrorClientCertificateRejected = -1205,
NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired = -1206,
NSURLErrorCannotLoadFromNetwork = -2000,
NSURLErrorCannotCreateFile = -3000,
NSURLErrorCannotOpenFile = -3001,
NSURLErrorCannotCloseFile = -3002,
NSURLErrorCannotWriteToFile = -3003,
NSURLErrorCannotRemoveFile = -3004,
NSURLErrorCannotMoveFile = -3005,
NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedMidStream = -3006,
NSURLErrorDownloadDecodingFailedToComplete = -3007
```

Comment: @calql8edkos The codes are the integers. The verbose names of those codes are usually enough to help debug. Feel free to add more description